# Tricky redirect/rewrite

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

I searched for this one, but found nothing ...

My old site is:    `cs.abc.edu/~cs4096`
My files were at:  `cs4096@cs.abc.edu/public_html`
My personal site:  `myname.com`
My Github Pages site: `myname.github.io`

When a user requests `cs.abc.edu/~cs4096` they are served `cs.abc.edu/~cs4096/index.html` and so on.

Via the ISP hosting `myname.com`, I setup a CNAME pointing `teaching.myname.com` to `myname.github.io` .

I want references to the old site, including pages below the top `index.html`, to be sent to `teaching.myname.com` where through the magic of DNS CNAME the URL goes to the `myname.github.io` site.  In other words, users still go to the `cs.abc.edu/~cs4096` but they are served from `github.io`.

The `teaching.myname.com` -> `myname.github.io` bit is working fine.  It’s the initial redirect/rewrite that is failing.  The problem is that the `~cs4096` is included in the URL when it is passed to `myname.com` .

That is, this

```
http://cs.abc.edu/~cs4096
```

ends up as

```
http://teaching.myname.com/index.html~cs4096
```

instead of

```
http://teaching.myname.com/index.html
```

and this

```
http://cs.abc.edu/~cs4096/Schedule
```

ends up as

```
http://teaching.myname.com/index.html~cs4096/Schedule
```

instead of

```
http://teaching.myname.com/Schedule
```

And, if you wonder WHY I’m doing two “redirects” here, it is because want the automatic rebuild of github pages that I can’t get at abc.edu or myname.com .

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ... I abandoned this idea and used an HTML Redirect.  It will mess up “Back” in the Browser, but it works.